# Applying \textfrench to item numbering inside lists written in Arabic

Tags: xetex, lists, polyglossia, arabic

**CONTEXT |** Bilingual document, Polyglossia in the preamble: Arabic=main, French=secondary (mostly for math). Used \textfrench to render page numbering and theorem numbering with the same font used in math content:

```
\newtheorem{defn}{تعريف}
\renewcommand{\thedefn}{\textfrench{\arabic{defn}}}
```

...

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} 
\lhead{\textfrench{\thepage}}
```

**ISSUE |** Couldn't figure how to apply that \textfrench to item numbers inside lists.

**EDIT |** I just want to have the same font for all numbers either in the French content (math) or the Arabic one (text). Already did it for theorem numbers and page numbers with the help of the \textfrench command, as shown in the piece of code. Still looking for achieving the same thing for item numbers inside lists: where do I need to apply that \textfrench command to do that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I hope that edit will do the thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> \renewcommand{\theenumi}{\textfrench{\arabic{enumi}}}